# Solving a system of simultaneous polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

This is the first time I have used Mathematica, so please bear with me. I'm trying to solve a system of $10$ nonlinear polynomial equations in $10$ unknowns, which I denote by $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, t$, subject to $4$ quadratic constraint equations (so essentially $14$ equations in $10$ unknowns). Here is my code:

```
Solve[{a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - d^2 == 4 && b^2 - e^2 - f^2 - j^2 ==-2 &&
       c^2 - f^2 - g^2 - h^2 ==-2 && d^2 - j^2 - h^2 - t^2 ==-2 &&
       a b - b e - c f - d j - 1 ==0 && b c - e f - f g - j h - 1 ==0 && 
       c d - f j - g h - h t -1 ==0 && d-j-h-t-1 ==0 && a-b-c-d-1 ==0 &&
       d b - j e - h f - t j -1 ==0 && c a - f b - g c - h d - 1 ==0 && 
       c-f-g-h-1 ==0 && d a - j b - h c - t d - 1 ==0 && b-e-f-j-1 ==0}
,{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, t}, Reals]
```

Every time I try to evaluate this, it returns a blank line. Is there something wrong with my code, that I'm not able to spot? Maybe I need to change the domain to rationals instead.

Comment: There appears to be 14 equations rather than 15 (just 4 quadratic constraints) and next to last equation has the `&&` missing just before it.

Comment: I fixed the code in my question.

Comment: Are you sure there is a solution to this system of equations? Most of the times, _Mathematica_ alerts the user if it cannot find a way to solve a problem; having no messages means that _Mathematica_ was successful in solving the equation (which in this case is "no solution").

Comment: If you are not concerned about being exact, try `NSolve` (which seems to give no solution as well).

Comment: There is no solution.

Comment: Just realized that I need to write a-b-c-d-1 ==0, so let me make that fix. Not sure if that will yield a solution.

Comment: Agreed, no solution after said fix either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new MMA user. I think we don't need {} for the equations.
EDIT: Deleted the redundant code to tidy-up.

Comment: The curly braces are optional. Thus, your code is identical to OP's code, except that it uses other symbols for equations and that it uses `Reduce`.